# How to solve this SQL problem and add dependency in two columns

Tags: sql-server

Only one account number & customer id for one specific customer should ever exist. But right now, I can insert the same account number and id for another customer name!

How to write a SQL query so that if one customer has an id and account number, I can't insert these values for another customer? Customer id and account number will be one and only for that one customer.

Here's a screenshot for illustration:

[image]

Comment: You should learn about `UNIQUE CONSTRAINTS`

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It seems you need some help with something but you didn't post any details at all or ask a question. I think Tab may be close to what you are struggling with.

Comment: Why are you using a `varchar` for `customer_id`? It's clearly an `int`.

Comment: Since `customer_id` and `account_number` make up your primary key, you already have made it impossible for two different customers to have the same account number.  There is nothing more you need to do.

Comment: for deposit i have to insert same account number for many times, but unique constraints does not allow it

Comment: @larnu that's a mistake :/

Comment: This question is one big contradiction!!!

Comment: Actually it sounds like this is just a bad database design.  A better design would make it much easier to do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really get what do you mean , but as I understand that you want to see for example data id =1  acc.number = A_1  should correspond for example only for customer JOHN
but also id=1 acc.number = A_2 also can be correspond to John

or id =1 and acc.number = A_3 (or id=2, acc.muber = A_1) can be correspond to Peter for example

in that case you should have that line when creating the table

```
Primary key (customer_id, account_number)
```

More here: https://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/2007/08/23/composite_primary_keys/

Comment: Question is sooo confusing, look at the screenshot, table already has this composite PK, I do not know what OP actually wants here.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using a compound Primary Key. In other words, the key is declared as (customer_id, account_number). This means that the combination of the two is guaranteed to be unique.

Based on your description, that is not what you want. You are asking for two keys, one key (customer_id) and another key (account_number).

Each table can only have one Primary Key. However, with a Unique constraint you can do exactly the same thing (logically), and you can create many Unique constraints.

In this case, you could change your Primary Key to just customer_id and then add a Unique constraint for account_number.